# What's wrong with this php ms sql query using temporary table

Tags: php, sql-server, phpquery

I am trying to build a query that uses temporary table in MS Sql and it returns nothing. 
I have inserted a sqlsrv_has_rows to see if it returns anything to no avail.  Here is the code.

```
include('../common.php');

$test = 'Begin '; 
$test .= "select *  into #t from trxreason ";
$test .= "select * from #t ";
$test .= 'End';
echo $test;
$testlist=sqlsrv_query($link,$test,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die('Cannot get location list');
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($testlist)){
echo "good";
}
while ($locrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($testlist,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $testarry[] = $locrow;
    }

print_r($testarry);
```

Can I use temporary table in this statement?
The below code without the temporary table works fine.

```
include('../common.php');

$test = 'Begin ';
$test .= "select * from trxreason ";
$test .= 'End';
echo $test;
$testlist=sqlsrv_query($link,$test) or die('Cannot get location list');
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($testlist)){
   echo "good";
}
while ($locrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($testlist,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $testarry[] = $locrow;
    }

print_r($testarry);
```

Can I run the multiple queries in this transaction statement?

Comment: Temp tables are available to PHP. Have you checked the query to make sure that the second table actually gets populated?

Comment: Yes I tested the code in sql management studio first.

Comment: PHP is not reporting any errors? Check the error log.

Comment: No errors are being reported.

Comment: I know when I use a construct like that with .NET, the two statements will return two result sets. If that's the case with the SQLSRV package, you're looking at the first result set after your `sqlsrv_query` call, and that will have no records because it's the result of the INSERT. Try using [`next_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php) to move to the result from the `SELECT`.

Comment: Ed you were right.  Now the issue becomes this. I am going to build a complex query on the fly based on what the user asks for in fields and criteria.  How can I get the last result set?